# Student Excam Seating Arrangement System Algorithm with Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am creating a student exam seating arrangement. I assign students to 4 groups. Students in the same group will not sit next to each other.

I am creating a student exam seating arrangement. I assign students to 4 groups. Students in the same group will not sit next to each other. But there is a situation. Since the number of students in the group is not close, the increasing group students have to come together. How can we make an algorithm to solve this problem?

Let's say the student numbers are as follows:
1st group : 180 students
2nd group : 150 students
3rd group : 140 students
4.group : 90 students

I choose students from random groups. Since the 1st group is too much here, I need to draw more randoms from that group so that I can reduce the number.

According to the number of students in the groups, the algorithm should make decisions like artificial intelligence.

Comment: Since your algorithm is the one that assigns students to groups, how can some groups have more students? just assign students the following way A, B, C, D, A, B, C, D...  so each group has a maximum of 1 student of difference with respect to the others. Then starting with the biggest group assign sits as A,B,C,D,A,B,C,D. So for example if A=3 B=3, C=2, D=2 your sitting sequence will be A,B,C,D,A,B,C,D,A,B  if a new student comes, assign it to group C and sit it at the end. Another student comes: group D and sit at the end.

Comment: Hello. A few questions: What does the room look like? How many seats are there? Are the seats arranged on a 2d grid? If so, how many rows and columns?

Comment: If it's one-dimensional, then here is a simple solution using [module `more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.interleave_evenly): `from more_itertools import interleave_evenly; groups = ['A'*180, 'B'*150, 'C'*140, 'D'*90]; print( ''.join(interleave_evenly(groups)) )`

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score -2):

### 1-dimensional

This function is already implemented as `interleave_evenly` in [module `more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.interleave_evenly).

```py
from more_itertools import interleave_evenly

groups = ['A'*180, 'B'*150, 'C'*140, 'D'*90]

seats = ''.join(interleave_evenly(groups))

print(seats)
# ABCDABCABCDABACDABCABCDABABCDABCACDABCABDABCABCDABCADABCABCDABCABCDABACDABCABCDABABCDABCACDABCABDABCABCDABCADABCABCDABCABCDABACDABCABCDABABCDABCACDABCABDABCABCDABCADABCABCDABCABCDABACDABCABCDABABCDABCACDABCABDABCABCDABCADABCABCDABCABCDABACDABCABCDABABCDABCACDABCABDABCABCDABCADABCABCDABCABCDABACDABCABCDABABCDABCACDABCABDABCABCDABCADABCABCDABCABCDABACDABCABCDABABCDABCACDABCABDABCABCDABCADABCABCDABCABCDABACDABCABCDABABCDABCACDABCABDABCABCDABCADABCABCDABCABCDABACDABCABCDABABCDABCACDABCABDABCABCDABCADABCABCDABCABCDABACDABCABCDABABCDABCACDABCABDABCABCDABCADABC
```

Note that if the groups are too uneven, there might not be a perfect solution:

```py
groups = ['A'*20, 'B'*4]  # too many students in group A
                          # inevitable some students of group A will sit next to eachother

seats = ''.join(interleave_evenly(groups))

print(seats)
# AAABAAAAABAAAAABAAAAABAA
```

### 2-dimensional

You need to specify the number of rows and columns in your classroom.

Here is a solution that places the students, then randomly transposes students until it finds a solution.

```py
from more_itertools import interleave_evenly, chunked
from random import randrange

def get_approx_seats(n_rows, n_columns, groups):
    n_students = sum(1 for g in groups for _ in g)
    n_empty = max(0, n_rows*n_columns - n_students)
    seats_1d = list(interleave_evenly(groups + [[None] * n_empty]))
    room = list(chunked(seats_1d, n_columns, strict=True))
    return room

def neighbourhood(room, r, c):
    n_rows, n_columns = len(room), len(room[0])
    for r2, c2 in ((r,c), (r-1, c), (r, c-1), (r+1, c), (r, c+1)):
        if 0 <= r2 < n_rows and 0 <= c2 < n_columns:
            yield room[r2][c2]

def get_coords_for_swap(room, r1, c1):
    n_rows, n_columns = len(room), len(room[0])
    for _ in range(2 * n_rows * n_columns):
        r2, c2 = randrange(n_rows), randrange(n_columns)
        if room[r2][c2] not in neighbourhood(room, r1, c1):  # student r2,c2 can move to r1,c1
            if room[r1][c1] not in neighbourhood(room, r2, c2):  # student r1,c1 can move to r2,c2
                return True, r2, c2
    # reaches here only if no good seat was found
    return False, randrange(n_rows), randrange(n_columns)

def exam_seats(n_rows, n_columns, groups):
    room = get_approx_seats(n_rows, n_columns, groups)
    some_students_still_adjacent = True
    while some_students_still_adjacent:
        some_students_still_adjacent = False
        for r1 in range(n_rows-1):
            for c1 in range(n_columns-1):
                if room[r1][c1] in (room[r1+1][c1], room[r1][c1+1]):
                    swap_went_well, r2,c2 = get_coords_for_swap(room, r1, c1)
                    room[r1][c1], room[r2][c2] = room[r2][c2], room[r1][c1]
                    some_students_still_adjacent = some_students_still_adjacent or not swap_went_well
    return room
```

Application with your four groups of 90 to 160 students, in an exam room with 12 rows and 47 columns:

```py
groups = ['A'*180, 'B'*150, 'C'*140, 'D'*90]
room = exam_seats(12, 47, groups)
room_string = '\n'.join(''.join(c or ' ' for c in row) for row in room)
print(room_string)
# ABCDABDABADACABDABCABCACACACACDACBCACACDADABABC
# BCABDABDABABABCBCDABADBACBCDBABCBABCABDABCDADCA
# ABCACBACDACABCDADABABADCBCBACDABACDABCABCACBCAB
# BCACACDABCABCABDABADCBCBCACDABDABDBCDACDABDCACA
# DABACABCABDCBCDADCDADCACBCA BDABCACDABABCDABCBA
# CDACBCABC ABADABCDBDABCBABCBCABDACDABADCACBADCA
# ABCDABCABABABABCBACABCACBADADCACBDCBCDCDCACBCAB
# BDABCABDABACABCBCDACDABACDCDBABACABCABDABCACBCB
# CABADBCBDACABCDABABABCACBCDACDABACDABCABCACBADC
# ACACACDABCACDAB ABADCACDABCBABCABDBCDACDABDADBA
# CABACABCABDABCDCBC CDCDABCDABDABCADBACABCDABACB
# BDABABDABCABABABCABDABCBADABCABDABCABADABABABAB
```